# How many ordered bases are there of the vector spaces $\mathbb{F}_3^2 $ and $\mathbb{F}_3^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb{F}_3$ be the field with 3 elements. I have defined the vector space which contains 9 vectors as;
 $$V=\mathbb{F}_3^2=\left\{(x_1,x_2)\mid x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{F}_3\right\}=\left\{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)...(2,2)\right\}.$$

Similarly, for $V=\mathbb{F}_3^3$, we have;
$$V=\mathbb{F}_3^3=\left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mid x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \mathbb{F}_3\right\}= \left\{(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,2)...(2,2,2)\right\}.$$ This vector space contains 27 vectors. Have I defined these sets spaces correctly? And if so, how would I go about working out the number of ordered bases in these?

Thanks

Comment: Bases are minimal spanning sets, so it is at least reasonable to consider that they may contain fewer vectors than all the possible vectors in the vector space.

Comment: For $\mathbb{F}_3^2$, if you choose a non-zero vector $v$, then any other non-zero vector $w$ which is not a scalar multiple of $v$ yields a basis $\left\{v,w\right\}$. Moreover, any basis can be obtained in this fashion. In how many ways can you make those choices?

Comment: @Mathematician42 that makes sense, so for example (0,2) and (1,0) yields a basis? Is there a formula for how these can be found without simply counting? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes there is, the number of bases is the same as the number of invertible matrices over the field in question of the proper size. Concretely, the number of bases of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ is the number of elements in $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$. This is given by $(q^n-1)(q^n-q)\dots (q^n-q^{n-1}).$ The proof of that formula is usually a counting argument though.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Thanks, so for the vector space F^2, the number of ordered bases is=(3^2-1)(3^2-3)=(8)(6)=48? and by a similar method, the number of ordered bases of F^3 is 11232?

Comment: Yes that's correct.